# Accessing a full dictionary java

Tags: java, dictionary

Im coding an AI that plays the game Word chain. if you don't know what that is here's a: [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_chain).

So Id like to make my AI better by having the ability to access an entire dictionary and search through words based on my parameters. How would I be able to access an entire dictionary via eclipse, using java?

Comment: An entire dictionary?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. There are a ton of ways to store and access a list of words.

Comment: What kind of search parameters? Depending on what you want to search for, you might want to use a different data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the main game rule is that the next word should start with the last letter of the previous word, you definitely want to prepare the data structure upfront and then access it in O(1). Therefore, I would recommend to use an array of the alphabet size (e.g. 26 for English) whose elements are HashSet instances representing the bag of words starting with the corresponding letter.

```
HashSet<String>[] words;
```

In fact, given an array, you can immediately access the set of words starting with that letter (position 0 -> A, position 1 -> B...). Alternatively to the array, you can use a HashMap, whose key is a letter and whose elements are again HashSets of possible words.

```
HashMap<Character, HashSet<String>> words;
```

So, access is still granted in O(1).

Concerning the HashSets, you want to have both constant access time and constant remove time, because words cannot be repeated during the game, so, after using them, you want to drop them off the HashSet.

If your dictionary is small enough (or, from another viewpoint, you have enough resources), you can entirely prefetch the dictionary. In case you don't, the proposed structures are still adaptable: in fact, the array (or the HashMap) is not going to change, while the HashSet also offers constant add time. So you may plan on refilling the HashSet from time to time (e.g. after a given amount of remove actions).

In all cases, you can always get the first element in the HashSet or introduce some randomization; keep in mind that access to HashSet elements does not happen in any particular order, as a general rule.

The source for reading the words can easily be a file or, even better, a bag of files, one per alphabet letter, so that you always know where to read and you can open all of them and tear down the overhead of opening, closing or seeking into the file: you open and close once each file and your seeking is just linear.

Finally, in case you also want to propose only words belonging to a given category, you may want to filter out the words not belonging to that category during dictionary prefetching (assuming you have the categories each word belong to).

If your problem also includes looking for a "related" word at runtime, then you may want to use **[Feature vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_vector)**, so that you can still have acceptable computation time to calculate correlations during the game.

Answer (score 0):

Try googling "word list". Here's a good one: http://wordlist.aspell.net/

Save one of these as a file and load it into memory with java. I would be more specific, but you will load it into memory differently depending on how you want to search the words.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of AI are you trying to build? Is it a learning agent?
From what I understand 'search through words based on the parameter', I suppose you mean you want to put words into different category, so that your AI will be able to generate a list of words that can be solved.

To create a word domain, you can always store your list of words into a hashmap, and put the 'parameter' as your key. Since you are trying to store the entire dictionary, why don't you store the information into a non-relational database(if applicable), so that you don't have to prepare the AI every time when you star the game.

Non-relational database can be easily implemented in Java. The one that I know that's easy to configure is RIAK. You can see the description and tutorial here: http://basho.com/riak/. Using non-relational database if similar to searching for things with a 'key word'.

Hope that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think that you need to communicate with a dict server to get access to the entire dictionary
This is my code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dictionary {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String host = "dict.org";
    try {
        Socket soc = new Socket(host,2628);
        OutputStream out = soc.getOutputStream();
        String request = "DEFINE ! yourwordhere";
        out.write(request.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        soc.shutdownOutput();
        InputStream in = soc.getInputStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        while(s.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        soc.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot found the host at "+host);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

}
If so you don't have to do any search and it would reduce the time of executing the program